# Jquery how to append c# variable to url in razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, string, razor

I have a razor page like this :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "mypage";
    string ApiAddress = "https://localhost:8114/api/";
 }

 <div>
     ...
 </div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function show(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: @ApiAddress + "UserApi/Getbyid=" + id,
            dataType:"json"
        });
    }
    </script>
 }
```

I want to create url using c# variable and jquery string. But i get an error.

```
  https://localhost:8114/api/ + "UserApi/Getbyid=?id=" + id
```

The url is not constructed correctly. How can i append c# variable and string in javascript ?

Comment: When you insert C# variables into a view, the values are inserted directly into the page with no extra processing. You need to add quotes so JavaScript knows it's a string, otherwise it's just kind of there and JavaScript doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks Can you write the correct sentence?

Comment: Just add quotes around `@ApiAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing the single quotes around the `@ApiAddress`

```
function show(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '@ApiAddress' + "UserApi/Getbyid=?id=" + @id,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```